# The refresh token has expired due to inactivity

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, azure-ad

Issue when running Add-PnPTeamsTeam. In the background this commandlet is using the following SharePoint API /_api/groupsitemanager/EnsureTeamForGroup to create a new team for this sitecollection.

**Expected behavior**

Connecting a newly created team to the connected sitecollection

**Actual behavior**

Add-PnPTeamsTeam is throwing an odata error with the following text

Add-PnPTeamsTeam : {"odata.error":{"code":"10001","message":{"lang":"nl-NL","value":"AADSTS700082: The refresh token
has expired due to inactivity.\u00a0The token was issued on [date] and was inactive for

**Steps to reproduce behavior**

1. Connect-PnPOnline -Url [SiteCollectionUrl] -Credentials (Get-Credential)
2. Add-PnPTeamsTeam

**Steps performed to solve this problem**

- Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken
- Revoke-AzureADSignedInUserAllRefreshToken
- Revoke-SPOUserSession

All of those commandlets don't refresh the refresh token within SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the New-SecMgmtAccessToken cmdlet to acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory.

For more information, refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/secmgmt/multi-factor-auth?view=secmgmtopenps-1.0

Comment: Thanks for you're feedback, but acquire an access token is not the issue for my opinion. We need to have a new "refresh token" from Azure AD. Connecting with the above command-let gives finally a page with the following error: AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application. The reply URL specified is the following: https://[tenant].sharepoint.com. Is this correct when register an application in Azure AD?

Comment: - $credential = Get-Credential
- New-SecMgmtAccessToken -ApplicationId 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' -Scopes 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -Tenant 'yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy' -UseAuthorizationCode

Comment: I could reproduce your issue per my test, still show the error, the refresh token expired, I suggest you open a ticket with Microsft to check if there is something error with the command.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Using: Connect-PnPOnline -Url [SiteCollectionUrl] -UseWebLogin and then Add-PnPTeamsTeam does work. But we need to use CredentialManager becase of automated install